# Number of unique values for rank correlation to be valid

Tags: correlation, references, ranks

Are there any recommendations on a *minimum number* of unique rank values per variable for either rank correlation coefficient or significance of this coefficient to be valid. Is it recommended to switch to the analysis of the association between nominal variables ($\chi^2$ test, Fisher test, Cramer's V, etc.) if there are less than, e. g., 5 different ranks? What are the cons and pros? 
Could you recommend any references on this issue?